# interpolating missing dates into a map containing a list of dates

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a map

```
Map<String, List<DateValue>> values;
```

DateValue is defined as:

```
class DateValue {
    Timestamp date;
    Double value;

    Timestamp getDate() { return this.date; }
    void setDate(Timestamp date) { this.date = date; }
    Double getValue() { return this.value; }
    void setValue(Double value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

I want to normalise all the `List<DateValue>>` lists in the map so that each `List<DateValue>` starts on the day of the minimum date (across the map), and each array has the same number of elements up to the maximum date (across the map).

Each array has a zero value for each missing day in the range.

```
"A": [{ 1/1/2018: 2 }, { 4/1/2018: 10 }, { 10/1/2018: 11 }]
"B": [{ 2/1/2018: 1 }, { 7/1/2018: 13 }, { 15/1/2018: 56 }]
```

Should result in:

```
"A": [
      { 1/1/2018: 2 }, { 2/1/2018: 0 }, { 3/1/2018: 0 },
     { 4/1/2018: 10 }, { 5/1/2018: 0 }, { 6/1/2018: 0 },
      { 7/1/2018: 0 }, { 8/1/2018: 0 }, { 9/1/2018: 0 },
    { 10/1/2018: 11 }, { 11/1/2018: 0 }, { 12/1/2018: 0 },
    { 13/1/2018: 11 }, { 14/1/2018: 0 }, { 15/1/2018: 0 },

"B": [{1/1/2018: 0 }, { 2/1/2018:1 } ... { 15/1/2018: 56 }]
```

... and so on for "B". I could query the min and max values, and iterate whilst searching but it seems inefficient. For what it's worth the dates are sorted.

Is it possible to do this with a set of `stream()` queries?

Comment: .. and you have tried?

Comment: iterating over the date range, and searching the map, which is not efficient

Comment: `Timestamp` seems to be the wrong type to use for your dates. The class is also long outdated. Today use `LocalDate` from [`java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `java.time` is also so much nicer to work with than the old-fashioned classes.

Comment: Is each list guaranteed to be sorted by date?

Comment: Find the min and max value across the map. Use `LocalDate.datesUntil()` to find all relevant dates. Store them into a total date list. For each list in the map. fill in 0 date value objects for the dates that are in the total date list but not in the list in the map. If runtime efficiency is a serious concern, look up a merge algorithm for filling in the missing objects.

Comment: As an aside, when you use 0.0 for a missing value, you probably shouldn’t use `Double` objects, better primitive `double` for the values.

Comment: @Ole yes they are sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the min and max date does not really have a big impact on the overall performance, since you know that your lists are ordered and you can hence directly narrow the comparisons to the first/last elements of each list.

```
LocalDate minDate = input.stream()
                         .map(l -> l.get(0).getDate())
                         .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                         .get();
LocalDate maxDate = input.stream()
                         .map(l -> l.get(l.size() - 1).getDate())
                         .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                         .get();
```

A stream based solution for padding the lists could now look like this:

```
input.stream()           // when using Java 9, use LocalDate.datesUntil() instead of building the stream of dates yourself
     .map(list -> Stream.iterate(minDate, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                        .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(minDate, maxDate) + 1)
                        .map(date -> list.stream()
                                         .filter(value -> date.equals(value.getDate()))
                                         .findAny()
                                         .orElse(new DateValue(date, 0.0)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

While consise, we do have to stream the lists again and again for each date to check whether they already contain a value for that date.

In order to reduce iterations when padding the lists, you can employ iterators to keep track where you are in the list instead of looping/streaming again and again through the whole list until you find an equal or later date:

```
input.stream().map(list -> {
    ArrayList<DateValue> padded = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<DateValue> iterator = list.iterator();
    DateValue next = iterator.next();

    for (LocalDate temp = minDate; !temp.isAfter(maxDate); temp = temp.plusDays(1))
    {
        if (next == null || next.getDate().isAfter(temp))
        {
            padded.add(new DateValue(temp, 0.0));
        }
        else
        {
            padded.add(next);
            next = iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
        }
    }

    return padded;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This should reduce the number of date comparisons from `#dates * averageListSize` to just `#dates`. That means the denser your data series are, the more date comparisons you save.

When trying both approaches with the example you provided, I got the same result (except for `A.13/1/2018`, which is 11 in your question, but should be 0, I think).

```
List<List<DateValue>> input = asList(new ArrayList<>(asList(new DateValue(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1), 2.0),
                                                            new DateValue(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 4), 10.0),
                                                            new DateValue(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 10), 11.0))),
                                     new ArrayList<>(asList(new DateValue(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 2), 1.0),
                                                            new DateValue(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 7), 13.0),
                                                            new DateValue(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 15), 56.0))));

Output: [[2018-01-01: 2.0,  2018-01-02: 0.0,  2018-01-03: 0.0,
          2018-01-04: 10.0, 2018-01-05: 0.0,  2018-01-06: 0.0,
          2018-01-07: 0.0,  2018-01-08: 0.0,  2018-01-09: 0.0,
          2018-01-10: 11.0, 2018-01-11: 0.0,  2018-01-12: 0.0,
          2018-01-13: 0.0,  2018-01-14: 0.0,  2018-01-15: 0.0],
         [2018-01-01: 0.0,  2018-01-02: 1.0,  2018-01-03: 0.0,
          2018-01-04: 0.0,  2018-01-05: 0.0,  2018-01-06: 0.0,
          2018-01-07: 13.0, 2018-01-08: 0.0,  2018-01-09: 0.0,
          2018-01-10: 0.0,  2018-01-11: 0.0,  2018-01-12: 0.0,
          2018-01-13: 0.0,  2018-01-14: 0.0,  2018-01-15: 56.0]]
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I needed - a concise intro to streams I am used to c# linq which tends to be simpler - your solution is well thought and thorough and I thank you!

Comment: I posted an incredibly similar question before that got no answers and several downvotes in a few minutes before - I don’t think stackoverflow is what it used to be. It’s people like you who make my faith hold

Comment: PS: this is not a homework assignment - it’s a legit problem - and the for loop solution sucks

Comment: @Jim glad that it helped. It was an interesting problem to think about. Not difficult, just interesting to look at different possibilities to tackle the comparisons. I guess your question could have gotten a more positive response if you had included code of your "classic" for/iterator based approach. That would have also made it clearer what part you wanted to improve/learn about. The [tag:java-stream] tag usually has many people ready to help with complete stream solutions as long as the question shows effort (that is **not** to say that yours lacks it, I think it's a good question).

Comment: My solution was very similar (so I’m not posting it now). One different detail was I used `LocalDate.datesUntil()` for producing all the dates between `minDate` and `maxDate` (inclusive). I found it nice.

Comment: @OleV.V. Definitely a useful convenience method, that's why I mentioned it in the comment in the stream code sample after seeing it metnioned in your initial comment on the question. I really need to convince my colleagues to update Java again...